# for column in Dataframe using pandas [Python]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have an excel file where I need to iterate over different columns, one at the time.

I'll give an example of the data and the way I am trying to resolve it.

| Nations | Population_N | Cities A | Population_A | Cities B | Population_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nation A | 100,000 | City C | 20,000 | City G | 10,000 |
| Nation B | 120,000 | City D | 15,000 | City H | 25,000 |
|  |  | City E | 5,000 | City I | 45,000 |
|  |  | City F | 60,000 | City J | 30,000 |

Where Cities A are part of Nation A and same with B; next to the column of the cities, the column of population for each of them.

I need to calculate what is the percentage of the population of each city over the population of the nation where they belong.

Hopefully I made clear the problem I'll show the way I'm trying to resolve the problem through pandas library in Python.

Code:

```
df = pd.read_excel("population.xlsx", usecols=['Nations','Population_N','Cities A','Population_A','Cities B, 'Population_B'])
results=[]
for i in df.iterrows():
     nation_ref=i[1]['Nations']
     pop_nation_ref=i[1]['Population_N']
     for column in df['Cities A', 'Cities B']:
         city_ref=[df[column].values]
         for column in df['Population_A', 'Population_B']:
             pop_city_ref=df[column].values
             perc_city_over_nation=(pop_city_ref/pop_nation_ref)*100
             r=(nation_ref,pop_nation_ref, city_ref, pop_city ref, perc_city_over_nation)
             break
         result.append(r)
```

---

I already know there are few errors (*I'm still learning Python and Pandas both*).

I'm willing to understand how I can switch columns in the line `for column in df['Cities A', 'Cities B']:` because even if the code read the whole column, when the for loop restart, it starts to read again the same column and mess up the calculus for the percentage.

The output that I'm expecting, beside the known data, is something like:

| Perc% A | Perc% B |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | 8.33 |
| 15 | 20.83 |
| 5 | 37.5 |
| 60 | 25 |

Thanks in advance for everyone willing to help.

Comment: can you add to this an example of the output table you expect? That will make it easier for answers to be checked against what you want

Comment: @34jbonz Done, beside the known data of the initial dataframe, I'm expecting a dataframe from the array "r" where the percentage of each city over the nation where it belongs is displayed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply defining new columns based on already existing columns. Your example outcome needs to be the full expected table to make sure this formula is correct, but you want something similar to this I believe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Nations':['Nation A', 'Nation B', 'Nation C', 'Nation D'],
        'Population_N': [100000, 120000, 300000, 805000],
       'Cities_A': ['City C', 'City D', 'City E', 'City F'],
       'Population_A': [20000, 15000, 5000, 60000],
       'Cities_B': ['City G', 'City H', 'City I', 'City J'],
       'Population_B': [10000, 25000, 45000, 30000],
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Let's look at the data:

```
print(df)
    Nations  Population_N Cities_A  Population_A Cities_B  Population_B
0  Nation A        100000   City C         20000   City G         10000
1  Nation B        120000   City D         15000   City H         25000
2  Nation C        300000   City E          5000   City I         45000
3  Nation D        805000   City F         60000   City J         30000
```

Now, create new columns (read more [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pandas/pandas-add-column-based-on-another-column/)):

```
df['Perc%_A'] = df['Population_A']/df['Population_N'] * 100
df['Perc%_B'] = df['Population_B']/df['Population_N'] * 100
```

Let's look at the output:

```
print(df)
    Nations  Population_N Cities_A  Population_A Cities_B  Population_B  \
0  Nation A        100000   City C         20000   City G         10000   
1  Nation B        120000   City D         15000   City H         25000   
2  Nation C        300000   City E          5000   City I         45000   
3  Nation D        805000   City F         60000   City J         30000   

     Perc%_A    Perc%_B  
0  20.000000  10.000000  
1  12.500000  20.833333  
2   1.666667  15.000000  
3   7.453416   3.726708
```

If my understanding of the formula for your percent columns is incorrect, please update your question with an example of the entire expected output. The current example does not provide complete information.